# Modify objects in resutl array when combining two arrays into one

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays of objects (Array1 and Array2) that I must combine in one array (result).

If an value is present in both arrays, it should be only once in the final array.

If a value is not present in any of the arrays, it needs to be added with the boolean set to true.

Here's the situation:

```
const Array1 = [
{value: "id1", name: "Element1", boolean: false}, 
{value: "id2", name: "Element2", boolean: false}, 
{value: "id3", name: "Element3", boolean: false}
]

const Array2 = [
{value: "id1", name: "Element1", boolean: false}, 
{value: "id2", name: "Element2", boolean: false}, 
{value: "id4", name: "Element4", boolean: false}
]
```

Expected output:

```
const result = [
{value: "id1", name: "Element1", boolean: false}, 
{value: "id2", name: "Element2", boolean: false}, 
{value: "id3", name: "Element3", boolean: true}, 
{value: "id4", name: "Element4", boolean: true}
]
```

Comment: @evolutionxbox the main issue I have is setting the boolean to true if an element is not present in one of the arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve the result using [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
const Array1 = [
  { value: "id1", name: "Element1", boolean: false },
  { value: "id2", name: "Element2", boolean: false },
  { value: "id3", name: "Element3", boolean: false },
];

const Array2 = [
  { value: "id1", name: "Element1", boolean: false },
  { value: "id2", name: "Element2", boolean: false },
  { value: "id4", name: "Element4", boolean: false },
];

const map = new Map(Array1.map((o) => [o.value, [o]]));
Array2.forEach((o) =>
  map.has(o.value) ? map.get(o.value).push(o) : map.set(o.value, [o])
);
const result = [...map.values()].map((arr) =>
  arr.length > 1 ? arr[0] : { ...arr[0], boolean: true }
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output full height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```